# How do i check i am Inside of House or outside of House using android Device?

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-sensors

Have any sensor that detects the android device is inside of a house or outside of 
 a house. If I use light sensor it gives me an error because when I detect in night mood its give me wrong information. How do I check that?

Comment: How is it supposed to know?

Comment: Why would you think a device would have an indoor/outdoor sensor? How is it supposed to tell the difference?

Comment: @kenWhite have any option for that ? i mean any other way to detect this type of problem ?

Comment: I asked you **How would you think the device would tell if it was indoors or out?** What information would a sensor use to tell the difference? There is no way to tell if the device is indoors or out. Would you expect it to scan to see if there were stars visible in the sky, or whether there were bathroom or cooking odors?

Comment: @keWhite i havn't idea about that  thats why i am asking you. sorry

Comment: @kenWhite I understand what you mean. But if there any way to detect this type od scenario ?

Comment: For the third time, **how would you expect to detect it?**

Comment: Maybe if you use GPS and define what home means. Or check if you are connected to the home wifi and assume that you cannot connect to it from outside (android.net.wifi.WifiInfo.getSSID).

Comment: @vakio: GPS does not have the accuracy to tell if you're standing on the inside or outside of a wall, and I know of no wifi signal that works on the inside of a building but not immediately outside (with the exception of specially shielded buildings).

Comment: @KenWhite I think there is no way to detect this

Answer (score 0):

That is not currently possible. Device location can be acquired using cell towers, GPS or marked WIFI spots if it is connected to one.

Whether you are indoors or not is a different issue all together and in most cases, GPS does not penetrate buildings well while cell tower signal deteriorates especially in basements.

Comment: Let's add Bluetooth beacons to the list just for fun, but they'll have all the same problems as Wi-Fi hot spots.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen sure, why not ha ha